# Pandas read_CSV reading into one column, won't seperate on ","

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having issues getting a csv file to separate on the comma. Only option that has worked, is using excel Data--> Text to column, separate on comma. When I do this and open the file it will work, however everything  I try in python simply opens into one column. What am I missing?

In the first DF I attempt to open the csv and seperate into multiple columns. The second DF is the excel file after I have data-Text to column on the "," value.

9-16-17 to 9-30-17

Report Filter:
{Claim Status Code} (ID) = "P" And {Claim Source Code} (ID) = "X" And {Claim Source Code} (ID) = "X" And {Claim Fill Date} (ID)

General Purpose 1 (GP1) - Member CDD,"Member Name - Last, First","Product/Drug Label Name","Claim Fill Date","Submitted Unit Quantity","Total Days Supply","Total Copay Amount","Total Net Cost"

0026,"PERSON, FAKEONE","OTHERINFO TAB 875MG","9/26/2017","20","10","$8.75","$0.00"
0026,"PERSON, FAKETWO","INFORMATION 400/5ML","9/24/2017","200","10","$0.00","$0.00"
0026,"PERSON, FAKETHREE","DATAENTRY 40MG","9/25/2017","15","30","$0.00","$20.59"

[Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj7xw.png)

Comment: Prior to making the change in Excel, is each row represented by single strings?

Comment: 0026,"PERSON, FAKEONE","OTHERINFO TAB 875MG","9/26/2017","20","10","$8.75","$0.00"

This is an example of one row from the file.

Comment: I imagine that the quotes are causing issues since generally those aren't included in .csv files.

Comment: Should I strip the quotations prior to putting the information in a dataframe?

Comment: I can't replicate it via making the csv with that exact line in it multiple times (quotes included).

Comment: 9-16-17 to 9-30-17

Report Filter:
{Claim Status Code} (ID) = "P" And {Claim Source Code} (ID) = "X" And {Claim Source Code} (ID) = "X" And {Claim Fill Date} (ID) 

General Purpose 1 (GP1) - Member CDD,"Member Name - Last, First","Product/Drug Label Name","Claim Fill Date","Submitted Unit Quantity","Total Days Supply","Total Copay Amount","Total Net Cost"

0026,"PERSON, FAKEONE","OTHERINFO TAB 875MG","9/26/2017","20","10","$8.75","$0.00"
0026,"PERSON, FAKETWO","INFORMATION 400/5ML","9/24/2017","200","10","$0.00","$0.00"

Comment: Please edit that into the question so that I can copy/paste into a file knowing where the line breaks are (since you skip the first 5 lines)

Comment: I've also tried seeing what text to columns actually does. If I want to preserve the quotation marks, Excel will wrap each line in `"..."`, and text to columns will strip that out. Nothing fancy. However, having quotation marks in the CSV doesn't seem to cause me any issues reading into pandas. There's something else going on in your actual file.

Comment: I'm at a loss on this one completely, I have tried every way I can think of to replicate this behaviour but I haven't been able to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, ill work on modifying how its exported.

Answer (score 0):

When you export the excel file to csv, keep the text delimiter as none. Usually this is double quotes. Just delete this and save to csv and try to import with python.
Another option is use pandas.read_excel instead of read_csv.